# Ubuntu 14.04 completely freezing after logging in when 2 monitors plugged in

Tags: 14.04, freeze, crash, multiple-monitors

I came in to work today and logged in to my Ubuntu machine(Dell Optiplex 790).  The entire system froze once the desktop loaded.  If I press `CTRL+ALT+F2` doesn't get me into a shell either, so it's like the entire system is locking up.

I have tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` along with `unity` like some have suggested on certain sites, but that did not do the trick.

I'm really not sure how to track down what is causing the problem, or what would be causing it in the first place.  I don't have a NVidia graphics card or anything like that, and have had a working desktop for over a year.

What steps can I take to find the issue and resolve it?  I'm sure I need to provide more information, I just don't know what or how to get it.

Edit: I am able to open a guest session without any freezes.  I can also get into the terminal if I don't log in to my user profile through the GUI.  If I `CTRL+ALT+F2` at the login screen I can log in to my profile through the terminal.

This problem is also only present when 2 monitors are plugged in. Removing the secondary monitor stops the freezes, but I kind of need both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 straight from your login screen, logging into your user, and typing

`sudo chown -R user:user .`

replacing `user` with your username.  It could be that there are some configuration files which have been accidentally taken over by your root user.  If this fails, try creating a new user and see if you can log into the desktop with the new user.

Comment: What file should I change ownership on?

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you explain what this will do?  I'm not sure what the `.` does in this statement and I don't want to execute it without knowing.

Comment: The . refers to the current directory.  That should be your home directory on a fresh login.  The -R will do it recursively.  The more I look at your problem the more I doubt it will work, but everything in your home directory SHOULD be owned by it's user, so running this command will either fix the problem, fix other problems, or do nothing at all.

Comment: You could also use ~ instead of the dot, which would refer to the logged in user's home directory.  Do check to make sure you are in your home directory before executing with the dot.

Comment: @anonymouse, gotcha.  I'm trying a lot of various things to get this working again, but I'm thinking I might have to upgrade to 14.10.  Something in the last update really messed with my system apparently

Comment: 16.04 will be out in just a couple weeks now.  If you can hold out till then, it might make a cleaner transition.  14.10 has no LTS, and upgrading once should be cleaner than twice.  Have you tried setting up another user?

Comment: I have not yet.  I will give it a shot here in a few.  I'm reaching out to some colleagues to see if they have any ideas.  But that is a good call.  I will definitely hold out with my single monitor until 16.04

Comment: One other that could be worth trying would be installing another desktop environment such as XFCE, gnome, LXDE, KDE, etc.  askubuntu is asking to move this discussion to chat - if you want to, feel free.

Comment: Actually don't move it to chat.  I just discovered I don't have a high enough reputation with askubuntu.com to go into chats.  :D